# Get observable target in onCompleted

Tags: java, rx-java

I need to trigger several observable classes which are observable to act, then know when all of them have reached their `onCompleted` state.

My current appraoch is to track the completion of RxJava observables by adding them to a set as they are started, then I want to remove them from the set when their onCompleted() method fires.

How can I get the observable object itself from onCompleted?

I subscribe like so:

```
c.event().subscribe(this);
```

And the object represented by `this` implements Observer, and has the `onCompleted` method.

How to get the observable target in `this.onCompleted()`?

---

I attempted the following solution according to Tassos Bassoukos suggestion, but it does nothing:

```
Set<Observable<Void>> obs = new HashSet<Observable<Void>>();
//...
c.event().subscribe(this);
obs.add(c.event());
c2.event().subscribe(this);
obs.add(c2.event());
//...
Observable.merge(obs).lastOrDefault(null).doOnNext(foo -> {
    System.out.println("All Observers Done");
});
```

The All Observers Done message never prints, although each observer has reached the onCompleted() method.

Comment: Maybe a long shot: `c.event()`? :)

Comment: @marstran - I actually used the lambda to make the example shorter, but instead, it made it look like a dumb question :).  I just changed the question to reflect the true situation

Comment: Oh, I think I misread. I think I read "observable" instead of "observer".

Comment: This feels like an XY problem; the Rx Operators already do this for you - exactly why do you need to do this?

Comment: @TassosBassoukos I am new as of last night to RxJava, so I could easily to over-complicating it.  I need to trigger several observable classes to act, then know when all of them have reached their onCompleted state.  Feel free to direct me to a resource on how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I need to trigger several observable classes to act, then know when all of them have reached their onCompleted state.

```
Observable.merge(A,B,C).lastOrDefault(null).doOnNext(dummy -> {...})
```

However, you might want to use functional style, if the source observables have the same number of elements and you want to do somethinf with their results:

```
Observable.zip(A,B,C, (a,b,c) -> {....});
```

Edit: Oh, now I get it - try this:

```
Observable
.merge(c1.ecent(), c2.event())
.doOnCompleted(() -> System.out.println("All Observers Done"))
.subscribe(this);
```

Comment: I gave that a shot, but its not working as I expected.  Updated question.

Comment: Why do you need to subscribe `this` to the observables?

Comment: I've edited my answer with a solution that might work for you.

Comment: Yes, that's it.  Thanks!